# read np arrays in panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a set of data that looks like:

```
12 , 12 , 12 , 12    #Data 1
16 , 16 , 16 , 16    #Data 2
3  , 3  , 3  , 3     #Data 3
3  , 3  , 3  , 3     ..
2  , 2  , 2  , 2     ..
9  , 9  , 9  , 9     ..
15 , 15 , 15 , 15    ..
```

and the data are row wise, as shown.

Now, I need to use those data in `pandas`. Problem is, with my limited knowledge, panda reads data column wise, and not row wise.

So, (and for some other reason), I read the data in `numpy` and trying to read the numpy array to pandas as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas

names = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
data = np.genfromtxt("trial.dat", delimiter=',')
print(type(data))
print(data)
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns=names)
```

which is giving:

```
python3 mwe.py 
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[12. 12. 12. 12.]
 [16. 16. 16. 16.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 9.  9.  9.  9.]
 [15. 15. 15. 15.]]
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 4, placement implies 7
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (7, 4), indices imply (7, 7)
```

The mismatch is basically coming from names dimension, as  with

```
names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
```

and
    print(dataset)

I am getting:

```
class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[12. 12. 12. 12.]
 [16. 16. 16. 16.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 3.  3.  3.  3.]
 [ 2.  2.  2.  2.]
 [ 9.  9.  9.  9.]
 [15. 15. 15. 15.]]
      A     B     C     D
0  12.0  12.0  12.0  12.0
1  16.0  16.0  16.0  16.0
2   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
3   3.0   3.0   3.0   3.0
4   2.0   2.0   2.0   2.0
5   9.0   9.0   9.0   9.0
6  15.0  15.0  15.0  15.0
```

But in Pandas dataset, I want:

```
A    B 
12   16
12   16
12   16
12   16
```

etc, i.e. along row of and-array.

So, how I can read the np-ndarray to pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transpose the np_array

```
dataset = pandas.DataFrame(data=data.T, columns=names)
```